# Create Unity Launcher for file

Tags: unity, launcher, .desktop

how do you create a launcher for a file in unity?
I am currently trying to create a launcher for the side panel in unity that, when clicked, opens an executable file in my home directory. Is there any way to do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It was sadly marked as duplicate when the other answer doesn't explain how to do this in a GUI.